# Calculating the driving distance between two addresses Google API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-places-api

This was always working with no problem until about a month ago when it does not calculate the distance anymore and show the error message instead. Any ideas on what is going on with this code and how to fix it?

```
function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
            var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
            var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

            var request = {
                origin:start, 
                destination:end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    distanceInput.value = 
                    response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
                } else {
                //Show error message
                alert("Can't find road! Please try again!");
                clearRoute();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

They started charging for it.  You have to register at the following site, and start paying fees to use it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation

Comment: I already have my own API key and pay for the service, the problem seems to be with the code.

Comment: Gotcha.  In my case, it suddenly stopped working without warning, without them letting me know that it changed to a fee-based service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I needed to enable (Directions API) to have it working again.
Cheers!